# Get the unique values from two arrays of object and put them in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects

```
var arr1 = [
             {id='1', text='xyz'},
             {id='2', text='abcd'}
           ];

var arr2 = [
             {id='1', text='xyz'},
             {id='2', text='abcd'},
             {id ='3', text='pqrs'}
           ];
```

I need to a method to get the unique from two arrays by 'id' and put them in arr3 Array3 should be -:

```
var arr3 = [{id ='3', text='pqrs'}];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is basic iterative programming. Show some effort, please.

Comment: you can use  underscore libraries utility method ,**union_.union(*arrays):** 
`Computes the union of the passed-in arrays: the list of unique items, in order, that are present in one or more of the arrays.` ref : http://underscorejs.org/#union

Answer (score 1):

In for loop you have to select big array as per length wise and try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var arr1 = [
             {id:'1', text:'xyz'},
             {id:'2', text:'abcd'}
           ];

var arr2 = [
             {id:'1', text:'xyz'},
             {id:'2', text:'abcd'},
             {id :'3', text:'pqrs'}
           ];
var arr3 =[];
        for(var i = 0;i<arr2.length;i++)
        {
         var cnt =0;
            $.each( arr1, function( k, v ) {
                if(arr2[i].id == v.id && arr2[i].text == v.text)
                {   
                    cnt ++;
                }
            });
            if(cnt == 0){arr3.push(arr2[i]);}
        } 
  console.log(arr3);    
});
```